# adding function in prototype versus declaring it as variable in OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

What is the advantage or different adding a function onto the prototype object versus simply declaring it on the constructor's variable?

this is the same, this is how we call Person

```
const James = new Person('James')
James.greet()
```

Adding greet to prototype object

```
const Person = name => {
  this.name = name
}
Person.protoype.greet = () => console.log(`my name is ${this.name}!`)
```

Adding greet to constructor

```
const Person = name => {
  this.name = name
  this.greet = () => console.log(`my name is ${this.name}!`)
}
```

Does adding greet to constructor make duplicate of function when we call Person multiple times? I know the disavatange of object method have this problem, for example

```
const Person = () => ({
  name: '',
  greet: () => console.log(`my name is ${this.name}!`)
})
const James = Person('James') //greet copy 1
James.greet()
const Alice = Person('Alice') //greet copy 2
Alice.greet()
```

Comment: `Does adding greet to constructor make duplicate of function when we call Person multiple times?` Yes. Every time a script runs across the `function` keyword (or `=>`), it will create a new function. Better to have one single function all class members reference than to have tons of identical functions.

Comment: so you're discouraging `Adding greet to constructor` and use `Adding greet to prototype object` ?. As I know prototype is a shared function, so any new instance won't cause memory leak if we have tons of instance.

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure there are many questions about this already.

Comment: This is a duplicate, it was asked just a couple of days ago… just need to find a good answer.

Comment: ... `var a = new Person("a"), b = new Person("b");` adding `greet` it to prototype: `a.greet === b.greet => true` (only one function shared by all instances of `Person`) whereas adding it in the constructor: `a.greet === b.greet => false` (each instance gets its own copy of `greet` which is redundant and wasteful).

Comment: @RobG I think i know the answer, just want to double confirm. I see, I even make the `object way` in the last part of my question to verify something.

Comment: A constructor is really a function until you call `new` on it, then in becomes it's own separate Object. An Object Literal is already an Object. `constructor.prototype.greet =` affects every `new` instance, which could be a problem or a blessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does adding greet to constructor make duplicate of function when we
>   call Person multiple times?

Yes.While

> Adding greet to prototype object

can avoid above problems.

And function added in the `constructor` exists in the `instance` while function added in the `prototype` exists in the `prototype`.

So,you can add commom function in the `prototype` and custom function in the `constructor`

or normally we don't add custom function in the `constructor`.

When needed,we add custom function in the `instance` or add custom function in the `prototype`

example:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.name = arg
    this.customSayName = () => {
      console.log(this.name)
    }
  }
  sayName() {
    console.log(Person.name)
  }
}

let p1 = new Person('john')
p1.customSayName() //john
p1.sayName() //Person
console.log(p1.hasOwnProperty('customSayName'))//true
console.log(p1.hasOwnProperty('sayName'))//false
console.log(p1.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('sayName'))//true
console.log(p1.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('customSayName'))//false
```

Comment: but if you use framework like react, sometime you have to pass the function into constructor via props, how do you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
const Person = name => ({
  this.name = name
  this.greet = () => console.log(`my name is ${this.name}!`)
})
```

When you have it as part of your constrcutor, for every new instance , a copy of name and greet will be created.

Instead when you add it to prototype , only once the method will be created on prototype and we can reuse it